# Почему cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address возвращает null?

Tags: android, linux, adb, mac-address

У меня есть приложение, которое устанавливается на STB приставку.

Я пытаюсь в этом приложении с помощью команды: `Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address");` получить мак адрес, но эта строка возвращает **null**.

В тоже время, если через терминал ввести команду `adb shell "cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address"`, то в ответ получаю полноценный мак адрес.

Права доступа к файлу -r--r--r--, т.е. прочесть его могут абсолютно все пользователи.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как такое возможно?

Comment: вероятно потому, что у пользователя, от имени которого запускается ваша программа, несколько меньше прав, чем у пользователя `shell`, от имени которого выполняются на устройстве команды, вызванные как `adb shell команда`.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, да, я тоже об этом думаю, но не могу быть уверен в этом  на 100%, потому что есть другая STB приставка (другой производитель, но идентичный Android), там мак выводится нормально. И возможности у пользователей, кажется, одинаковые. Может быть можно как-то самому добавить права доступа к файлу, чтобы все их имели?
Сам файл тоже имеет такие права доступа: -r--r--r--, т.е. читать его могут абсолютно все, но он не читается

Comment: Важны не только права к файлу, но и права ко всем вышестоящим каталогам (впрочем, на моём личном андроиде все нужные права у каталогов есть)

Comment: goolge: [Programmatically getting the MAC of an Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11705906/4827341). не зря ведь авторы api обложили эту процедуру такими сложностями. где-то прямое обращение к псевдо-файловой системе *sysfs* может и «сработать», но полагаться на наличие такой «дыры» в произвольно взятом устройстве вряд ли оправданно.

Comment: @andreymal, да, я это предусмотрел, там доступ есть ко всем каталогам, в которых находится этот файл

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, ну, а есть способ обойти эту "дыру"? Просто мне обязательно нужно сделать так, чтобы мак адрес читался спомощью этого кода

Comment: вы же взломщик, вам не «обходить» надо, а проникать. там, где дыра есть — проникнете, где нет — читайте ваш вопрос. а как предусмотрено получать mac-адрес нужного сетевого интерфейса разработчиками api — написано, например, по приведённой ссылке.

Comment: Блокировать файлы могут Apparmor и SELinux... В андроиде SELinux вроде. чтоб он разрешил читать файл нужно в системную папку положить профиль вашей программы. Посмотрите какие есть профили уже. Может получится подогнать ваше приложение под какой-то из них

Comment: @eri, да, дело именно в SELinux. Сторонним приложениям нет доступа к sysfs и здесь либо просить доступ у производителей, либо использовать другой способ получения мак адреса

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вы были правы. Можете добавить ваши комментарии в виде ответа на вопрос.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧубаров, напишите ответ сами, пожалуйста. мне это сложнее сделать ввиду того, что я вообще не программист.

Answer (score 0):

На этой приставке для сторонних приложений запрещен доступ в sysfs. Чтобы получить мак адрес, пришлось его брать из проперти с помощью `ro.boot.ethaddr`